MUI theming – how do I access the color prop in the theme file for styling new variants more generically?
I am creating a new variant for a MUI button and I want the the color from the color prop to be applied as a border and text color.
The MUI docs suggest this approach which is not very generic/dynamic because I would have to address every available color separately:
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed' },
          style: {
            textTransform: 'none',
            border: `2px dashed ${blue[500]}`,
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed', color: 'secondary' },
          style: {
            border: `4px dashed ${red[500]}`,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});

I am looking for a solution like this:
styleOverrides: {
      root: ({ ownerState, theme }) => ({
        ...(ownerState.variant === 'dashed' && {
          borderColor: theme.palette[ownerState.color || 'primary'].main
        }),
      }),
    },

The line theme.palette[ownerState.color || 'primary'].main gives me a ts error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning", ButtonPropsColorOverrides>' can't be used to index type 'Palette'.

'inherit' as color definition does not apply the right color.
Edit:
I ended up with this solution for now, but I still do not find it a 100% satisfying as I have to define the eligable values in a new type when using typescript. So better solutions are still very welcome.
